# Is any full rank feature matrix unitary? If so, why?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, projection-matrices, unitary-matrices

If not, in feature engineering, why is $$X^T(Y-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY)=0$$ for a full rank feature matrix $X \in \Bbb R^{nd}$ and response values $Y \in \Bbb R^n$?

Comment: What's a feature matrix?

Comment: Just expanding it and calculating. Note $X^TX(X^TX)^{-1} = I$.

Comment: $(X^TX)^{-1}$ is abuse of notation. $X^TX$ could be singular, but engineers take short cuts.

Comment: If the matrices are real, why unitary instead of orthogonal?